# exporting large files in separate sheets Laravel Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel

I have 50,000 raw. I want export them but System fails to export it. I am using this code. Is there any better solution for this?

```
Excel::create('catalogDumptReport', function ($excel) use ($finalArray) {
        $excel->sheet('catalogDumptReport', function ($sheet) use ($finalArray) {
            $sheet->fromArray($finalArray);
            $sheet->setFontFamily('Verdana');
            $sheet->setFontSize(10);
            $sheet->row(1, function ($row) {
                $row->setFontWeight('bold');
            });
            $sheet->setBorder('A1', 'thin');
            $sheet->setHeight(1, 20);
        });

    })->export('xls')
        ->download('xls');
```

Comment: What do you mean by system fails, memory limit or...? Please post the query populating $finalArray

Comment: what's the error? I'm guessing,  out of memory? increase the php memory limit or split them across multiple files

Comment: system fails means system hang a lot. I increased memory too. No success. I am also trying to splitting them but Some how it is also not working. I am splitting them into 8000 per sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I advise against expoting such a large xls files (directly in the browser). The best way to do it (and the fastest) is to export it in the background (such as async Laravel Queue etc.).

There are mainly two computational complexity problem:

1. **time complexity** - which grows very fast what means that the time to download in this example will severely hrows too.
2. **complexity of memory** - which can exhaust all memory resources on the machine that can also exhaust all memory resources on the machine also very fast - what means that not only current system/program can act very slowly but every other lunched on this machine.

As I said the best way is to put this xle generating in to the background - but there's more:

You need to find a way to split the data and append it with a portions of data - not all at once. This can save the memory resources.

After you get export it in the queue you can check in the browser through
ajax request if the file is ready to download and let the user dowload already prepared xls file.